# Release notes after an update for users

Tags: usability

Stakeholders want to show release notes after an update of the system is released. And they want to show it once after the user has logged in. They want to put the information in a modal and so that the user can close it after he has scrolled down.

What do you think about it?

There are about 1000 users of this system.

Comment: What type of product are we talking about and who are the users? How sure are you that users will read such notes?

Comment: Is there an underlying problem this is supposed to solve? If it takes an average of 5 seconds to load and dismiss the modal, that would be 1.3 man-hours of work wasted across 1000 users with each update, not including the effort required to implement the "feature".

Answer (score 3):

### Release Notes

#### Version X++

- Add modal to show release notes after update.

Never show release notes again.

[<kbd>Close</kbd>](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/126180/115162)

Comment: This checkbox has been disabled for the stakeholders who requested this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Seems straightforward enough, having a Title, Version #, update notes, closing button. However consider these things:

1. What percentage of users will actually care to read the release notes?
2. If not many users will read the notes, why impose them to everyone?
3. Are there any other less obtrusive places to show the notes? For example in an App Store description (if we are talking about an app), or the login screen itself (beside the login form).
4. If showing the notes in a modal is inevitable, at least make sure it only shows up once for each user. It should not be shown again after the user closes it.
5. If users close such modal, but need to reference it later on, where can they find such notes?

Comment: Reasonable suggestions, but no option to not show release notes for users who simply aren't interested?

Comment: Option #3 shows the notes to the user, but they don't have to read them if not interested. It would be in the login form screen which they'll have to access regardless. If you want an option of not showing the notes altogether, then post them on a "press release" area of the website, or the app store description.